# Trying to understand Query Table operation in DynamoDB .NET

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm working with DynamoDB .NET and trying to understand it but I have a doubt doing the following sentence: "get all rows that have a specific value". For example, I have the following table:

Id | Company | Code

where Id and Company are the primary key (composed) and my query would be "get All codes belonging to a company with their ids"

I read that scan operations are more expensive than a query and if my table has a primary key that is composed of both a hash and range attribute I should use query sentences.

Ok, so I started to code my sentence and I have this:

```
Table table = Table.LoadTable(dynamoClient, tablename );

QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter();
filter.AddCondition("Company", QueryOperator.Equal, company); //company is a parameter

QueryOperationConfig config = new QueryOperationConfig()
{
    Filter = filter,
    Select = SelectValues.SpecificAttributes,
    AttributesToGet = new List<string> { "Id","Code" },
    ConsistentRead = true
};

Search tableResult = myTable.Query(config);
```

When I executed that, I have the following error:

> Cannot specify the AttributesToGet when choosing to get ALL_ATTRIBUTES

I read the documentation but I don't understand and I was watching this question [How to query range key programmatically in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282889/how-to-query-range-key-programmatically-in-dynamodb) but didn't help me.

It's clear that I'm not doing well and that my knowledge is limited. So, Is somebody can explain me how to implement a query or if I have to use the scan operation?

Thank so much.
If it is necessary more information, please let me know.

Comment: what is the structure of your table? What is the hash key? Do you have a range key? If yes what is the range key?

Comment: Ok, maybe I should be more specific, sorry. "Id" is the hash key and "Company" is the range key. Till now, I have only these tree fields, all of them are strings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, after searching and testing a lot of possible solutions to my problem, I could understand that what I was doing with my table was wrong. Here is the thing:

my table was composed by:

> - HASH KEY = id
> - RANGE    = Company
> - ATTRIBUTE NOT KEY = Code

and I wanted to get all the codes that have a specific company. So, I was trying to query the table using the RANGE condition instead of use the HASH KEY, that was wrong!

Changing the table model to

> - HASH KEY          = Company
> - RANGE             = id
> - ATTRIBUTE NOT KEY = Code

works perfectly

This explain everything ( from the oficial Amazon Dynamodb documentation )

> A Query operation finds items in a table or a secondary index using only primary key attribute values. You must provide a hash key attribute name and a distinct value to search for. You can optionally provide a range key attribute name and value, and use a comparison operator to refine the search results. By default, a Query operation returns all of the data attributes for items with the specified primary key(s); however, you can use the ProjectionExpression parameter so that the Query operation only returns some of the attributes, rather than all of them.

Here is the [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) if you want leear more about

[UPDATE]
After read more profoundly, I could understand the concept of GSI (Global Secondary Index). Respecting the initial model of my table and adding a GSI to [Company,Code], I could do my query without problems.

Comment: "So, I was trying to query the table using the RANGE condition instead of use the HASH KEY, that was wrong!".  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBContext.QueryScan.html. In this code sample, they are fetching range of data based on the Range key, not hash key

Comment: You are right. The condition is for the range key! Thanks.